# Multiple cursors in curses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am using ncurses in C/C++. I'm trying to get multiple blinking cursors, but so far I've been unsuccessful doing so. Is it possible in ncurses? Suggestions for similar library (C/C++ or Python) that supports this are also welcome.

Update: with "cursor" I mean a blinking block/line character, not an thing that receives input from the keyboard.

Comment: Why do you want or require multiple blinking cursors?

Comment: How about placing blinking underscores on the screen.  (There is only one text cursor.)

Comment: At which cursor do you expect input? Do you mean blinking character attribute?

Comment: @EdHeal For example, some text editors (like SublimeText) have a "multiple cursors" feature that allow users to type and make selections in multiple places at the same time. I could imagine someone trying to implement this feature in a terminal-based text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no, you can't do that

long: curses can only ask terminals to do things (and terminals don't do that).

Each window in a curses display can have its own cursor *position*, but the terminal will only show one cursor at a time.  If you ask for input, e.g., using `getch`, curses will put the terminal's *cursor* at the last position in the window where you moved it.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you can't *actually* have multiple cursors in your terminal, but you can simulate it.

Using ncurses, you could hide the actual cursor and use the [`chgat(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/chgat) family of functions to change the attributes of characters you want to appear as cursors. By doing this at multiple positions, your program appears to use multiple cursors.

This program highlights the "H" in "Hello" and the "w" in world with a reverse highlight, making it look like a cursor is hovering over each character. It then sleeps for 5 seconds and exits.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE);

    mvprintw(0, 0, "Hello, world!");
    mvchgat(0, 0, 1, A_REVERSE, 0, NULL);
    mvchgat(0, 7, 1, A_REVERSE, 0, NULL);
    refresh();

    sleep(5);

    endwin();
}
```